# How to group by in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I read a little about aggregation and even about collapsing. But Im afraid none of them fit my use case.
This is my case:

The database contains mutual interest. However, apart from basic mutual interest, there is something called triangle interest. Consider the following:

```
John owns a bmw and whats to change it with a porche
Paul owns a porsche and whats to change it with a bmw
```

Here we have a mutual interest. This is the entry in elastic:

```
{"parts": 
    [
        {"name": "John", "interested_in": "Paul", "response": "unseen", "car": "BMW"}
        ,{"name": "Paul", "interested_in": "John", "response": "unseen", "car": "PORSCHE"}
    ]
}
```

However, there is the use case when 3 parts are involved. Consider the following:

```
    John owns a bmw and whats to change it with a porche
    Jack owns a porsche and whats to change it with an audi
    Philip owns an audi and whats to change it with a bmw
```

We have  mutual interest involving 3 parts. This is the entry in elastic:

```
{"parts": 
    [
        {"name": "John", "interested_in": "Jack", "response": "unseen", "car": "BMW"}
        ,{"name": "Jack", "interested_in": "Philip", "response": "unseen", "car": "PORSCHE"}
        ,{"name": "Philip", "interested_in": "John", "response": "unseen", "car": "AUDI"}
    ]
}
```

In the case above, John will give his bmw to Philip. Jack will give his porsche to John. And Philip will give his audi to Jack.

Now, consider this new mutual triangle:

```
{"parts": 
    [
        {"name": "John", "interested_in": "Jack", "response": "unseen", "car": "BMW"}
        ,{"name": "Jack", "interested_in": "William", "response": "accepted", "car": "PORSCHE"}
        ,{"name": "William", "interested_in": "John", "response": "unseen", "car": "AUDI"}
    ]
}
```

As you can see, Jack is not interested in changing his porsche with John's BMW. However, thanks to triangle swap, there are two ways for John to get Jack's porsche.

So, what is the issue here? The issue is that I only want an entry for John's interest in Jack's porsche. Which has now two entries in elastic. John would also like to get that entry where there are most

```
{response: accepted}
```

But this query will give both triangle swaps (and also the direct swap John<->Paul):

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "parts.name": "John"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
  }
}
```

How can I solve this? With painless maybe?

The output wanted is this:

```
[
    {"parts": 
        [
            {"name": "John", "interested_in": "Paul", "response": "unseen", "car": "BMW"}
            ,{"name": "Paul", "interested_in": "John", "response": "unseen", "car": "PORSCHE"}
        ]
    }
    ,{"parts": 
        [
            {"name": "John", "interested_in": "Jack", "response": "unseen", "car": "BMW"}
            ,{"name": "Jack", "interested_in": "William", "response": "accepted", "car": "PORSCHE"}
            ,{"name": "William", "interested_in": "John", "response": "unseen", "car": "AUDI"}
        ]
    }
]
```

As you could see, the John->Jack was indexed twice before (in two differente swaps). But the one that shows in result list is only one of them. And it is the one where "most of the parts" have accepted the swap.

Comment: I thinck the data modeling is wrong with your use case. You have A => B B => A relationship, elastic wont do it (=join).
First the interrested_in should be a array (or nested), but if the trade must be done in real time, you will have to extract data and do it on application side imo.

Comment: How would you call the data modelling? Im trying to search for a data modeling that match my use case.

Answer (score 1):

### Elasticsearch can only *collapse* on a single-valued field.

In your case, you want to collapse around the value "John" (in `parts.name`) which is not single-valued, so you **can't** collapse and fully deduplicate *John's interest in Jack's Porsche* using the existing data model.

Your options are

1. Come up with a "John-centric" data model so you don't need to group results.
2. Rank swaps based on desired criteria and return only "the best for John"
3. Group results in code after retrieving search results in the client.

### The solution below works with option (2) and gives precedence to swaps closest to completion (by percentage accepted)

(This solution adds the field `interest` for your precedence logic.  You would need to calculate the *interest* value when writing or updating a swap to your **swaps** index)

---

This solution would ensure that

```
{"interest": 0.333, "parts": 
    [
        {"name": "John", "interested_in": "Jack", "response": "unseen", "car": "BMW"}
        ,{"name": "Jack", "interested_in": "William", "response": "accepted", "car": "PORSCHE"}
        ,{"name": "William", "interested_in": "John", "response": "unseen", "car": "AUDI"}
    ]
}
```

...is displayed as the preferred, higher-ranking (or only) match above...

```
{"interest": 0.0, "parts": 
    [
        {"name": "John", "interested_in": "Jack", "response": "unseen", "car": "BMW"}
        ,{"name": "Jack", "interested_in": "Philip", "response": "unseen", "car": "PORSCHE"}
        ,{"name": "Philip", "interested_in": "John", "response": "unseen", "car": "AUDI"}
    ]
}
```

...for a query that prioritizes swaps of interest to **John**.

In your case, the second swap is prioritized *because* 1/3 of the triangle swap has been accepted (meaning that the swap has **the highest percentage accepted**).

---

So here's what you need:

**1. Mapping for swap index**

```
PUT swaps
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "interest": { "type": "float" }, <-- added: precalculate this!
      "parts": {
        "type": "object",   <-- since precalculating `interest`, no need to be nested
        "properties": {
          "name":          { "type": "keyword" },
          "interested_in": { "type": "keyword" },
          "response":      { "type": "keyword" },
          "car":           { "type": "keyword" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Reindex with the `interest` values calculated and populated**

**3. Write a query to match `"part.name":"John"` but score using `interest`**

E.g.

```
GET swaps/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "constant_score": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "parts.name": "John"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "interest"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

...and verify that this returns all three of your swaps where **John** has interest as you'd currently expect (note that the scores now reflect that these swaps are ranked by the swap interest value or percentage accepted).

**4. "Faux Group By" options since you're filtered on John already**

- Show all swaps with interest: `"min_score": 0.1`
- Show only the highest interest swap `"size":1`

Comment: This seems to be a very good solution (option #2). At step #3 I got all results for John but with the interest-percentage. Being quite new to elastic, Im not really sure how to put the group-by directive in the search query. Would you mind sharing the missing part?

Comment: I tried by adding "size: 1" before the main query-object. But this will only return one single hit (while I was excpecting 2 hits: John is interested in Jack through 3 objects. But he is also interested in Paul. And that hit is not returned. Note that John-Jack has a max score at 0,4. While John-Paul has score at 0,3. If I change score for Paul to 0,5 then that hit will be returned. But Jack still not).

Comment: I also tried adding parallel to the query object this: ,"aggs": {"agg_label" : {"terms" : {"field" : "parts.interested_in","size" : 1}}}
However, then no grouping seem to be triggered as all the hits for john are returned (included 3 duplicates for John-Jack).

Comment: The `min_score` really only just filters out the swaps where no part has been accepted (assuming you don't have more than 10-way swaps).  In your case, it filters out "John's interest in Paul" since there was no response from Paul.

The GROUP BY you're looking for is unfortunately not available with your current index-structure, only filtering:

e.g. 

"return the single highest-interest swap" (`size:1`), or 


"return all swaps with any interest" (`min_score: 0.1`)

Comment: You could create a structure which was more "Person-centric" (vs "Swap-centric") so you wouldn't need to GROUP at all, but this would likely require some data duplication and additional moving parts to manage in the index.

I do understand your requirement a little better now though (maybe you can update your post with the expected result you've described).  You want all "cars" John is interested in (de-duplicating swaps around unique cars, and prioritizing swaps with interest while deduplicating.).

The challenge is the many-to-many relationship, which Elasticsearch struggles with.

Comment: You could keep your current index design intact (if needed by other features), and simply create a second separate index (e.g. `interested_party` index, with fields `name`, `car_of_interest`, `swap_id`, `swap_interest`) ... you'd maintain the second index (effectively a materialized view) independently, and run your GROUP BY ("name", "car_of_interest") there, allowing the "swap_interest" to inform the de-duplication.  (The reason GROUP BY would work there is because `name` and `car_of_interest` would be single-valued fields, unlike in your current index).

Comment: I understand. I am quite sure that the most suitable is a John-centric data model. This will cause quite much redundancy.
But I think it will be easier to query.
I still will update the question in case somebody could come with a non-john centric solution that is not too complex.